# How to add a tab dynamically when we click a button using React js and Bootsrap 4

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

How to add a tab Dynamically on button click

i have tried all examples but none of them helped me

For example :-
    below intially 2 bootstrap tabs are there Named Tab1 and Tab2 ..
    Add Tab button is there. 
    When we click on that automatically tab3 needs to bind 
    How to do this guyz give me suggetions please

Reference  Link :-
https://www.bootply.com/61679

Comment: Can you provide an example component you'd like to implement this for? You'd want to set the tab3 visibility in your component state

Comment: Hii @Kellen thanks for your quick response ... i want exactly the same implementation without ANY JQUERY or javascript can u check below link please https://www.bootply.com/61679

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without any javascript"? As in no other dependencies? ReactJS is javascript

Comment: sorry updating my question without JQUERY @Kellen

Comment: Can you update the question with already worked out code?

Comment: @sagarbhanu try my solution below, that should give you some insight on how to integrate this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose this would be the basic template you need to accomplish this feature in React.

See this sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wiles-w2uwh

### Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tabs: [
      { name: "Tab 1", content: "Wow this is tab 1" },
      { name: "Tab 2", content: "Look at me, it's Tab 2" }
    ],
    currentTab: { name: "Tab 1", content: "Wow this is tab 1" }
  };

  createTabs = () => {
    const { tabs, currentTab } = this.state;

    const allTabs = tabs.map(tab => {
      return (
        <li>
          <button
            className={currentTab.name == tab.name ? "tab active" : "tab"}
            onClick={() => this.handleSelectTab(tab)}
          >
            {tab.name}
          </button>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return <ul className="nav nav-tabs">{allTabs}</ul>;
  };

  handleSelectTab = tab => {
    this.setState({
      currentTab: tab
    });
  };

  handleAddTab = () => {
    const { tabs } = this.state;

    const newTabObject = {
      name: `Tab ${tabs.length + 1}`,
      content: `This is Tab ${tabs.length + 1}`
    };

    this.setState({
      tabs: [...tabs, newTabObject],
      currentTab: newTabObject
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { currentTab } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="well">
          <button className="add-tab-button" onClick={this.handleAddTab}>
            <i className="text-primary fas fa-plus-square" /> Add Tab
          </button>
          {this.createTabs()}
          <div className="tab-content">{currentTab.content}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Christopher ... i went through your code and its pretty good what i expected is the same and may i know one more thing now it was adding tab1, tab2 and so on right... how can we change tab names dynamically..For example i have created 4 tabs how can i change those tab names

Comment: @sagarbhanu I just added some additional functionality to the sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wiles-w2uwh   Take a look at the onBlur and DoubleClick event-handlers. That should give you a good idea of what is happening :). Also, please consider marking my solution as the answer and upvoting !

Comment: thanks bro upvoted @Christopher Ngo...I will take a look what u did on current snackbox ..

Comment: @sagarbhanu thanks bro! To active the tab-editting feature, just double-click on the tab you want to edit. When you are finished typing the new name, click away from the tab and it will be set :). Please mark as answer as well if it meets your requirements.

Comment: sure bro and can u take a look at this issue as well please i solved this in a diff way but i want a proper solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019906/how-can-we-use-react-dnd-properly-with-same-item-draggable-multiple-times-and-ap

Comment: @sagarbhanu yeah I can take a look. Currently driving to work right now :)

Comment: @ Christopher Ngo bro and i was implementing your code and i got a small dought i have succesfully added tabs concept to my project and for every tab i was using same component lets say MiddleContainer Component... i was using react Dnd for that when i drop something on that every tab was getting same output instead of getting diff pages...its happening Because of state i know that but how to tell when ever we click on tab new page should open and if already something dropped it should not arise

Comment: @sagarbhanu oh darn, we might have to take a look at all your react code for this component. I personally do not have much experience with the React DnD library, so I'll have to see what your code looks like to know whats happening. Please feel free to post another question on stackoverflow with the updated code you implemented with this concept, I'll take a look as soon as I'm free/home from work. I will definitely take a look when I'm at home. Just tag me. :) . It sounds like your feature is mostly working though and the scope of your original question has been answered.

Comment: sure bro @ Christopher Ngo ill repost with code snackbox so that u will get to know whats happening exactly and whats my dought..Thanks for replying

Comment: @sagarbhanu sweet! will be glad to help you some time today (Saturday). Just send me a message. For now, please consider marking answer as solution (green-check). :D

Comment: haha done bro sorry for delay :P  @Christopher Ngo .. when u are free just ping me here bro..

Comment: @ Christopher Ngo bro error when i mistakenly type same tab name for another tab issue was getting both two tabs are editing...and how to delete specific tab bro?

Comment: @sagarbhanu oh damn! Okay let me try to resolve those features today :)

Comment: @ Christopher Ngo sure bro get me back as soon as possible bro and try to modify how to delete tabs also bro..Thank You

Comment: @sagarbhanu hey bro! I just updated the sandbox with the features you need: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wiles-w2uwh.  To make sure we don't end up having two tabs updated at the same time we should give each tab a unique ID. I brought in the uuid() library that will create a randomized id for us and we can assign that to each tab. uuid() will be used during tab-creation. Additionally, see the a handleDeleteTab logic :)

Comment: thanks bro i will take a look now @ Christopher Ngo

Comment: @ Christopher Ngo  bro please take a look at this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147075/how-to-update-particular-object-in-array-of-multiple-objects-dynamically

Comment: @sagarbhanu yeah i'll take a look :)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro .. you are awesome @ Christopher Ngo...Kindly check above link bro how to i update inner array of objects with another object

Comment: @sagarbhanu you're welcome :). For the question in that link, are we pretty much using the same code as this sandbox, just with a nested array?

Comment: yes i need to update the state with this same tab concept i was maintaining an array in each tab object  @ Christopher Ngo

Comment: Hi @sagarbhanu I added an updated sandbox to your other question. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: sure bro @ Christopher Ngo and you are updating only name  in handleDetailChange method in that (check this const updatedTabs)   but what if i want to update total object instead of only name??? in above example only name is there but in my real scenario there are lot of variables in that object .. so i need to update whole object not a single name how to do that bro

Comment: @sagarbhanu oh that shouldn't be too difficult, can you give me an idea of what the entire object looks like inside the Dropdown details? Put a screenshot or the code in the other question :)